# C# If i click button2 (in form2) , label1 show in form 1

Tags: c#, winforms

i need code to my program : I click to buton1 , and form2 show , in form2 i click for button2 , and in form1 show label1 "WORK" . Can anyone help me write this code ??

Comment: I'm afraid no one is going to write your code for you. Please show the code you have tried, and point out where you got stuck and need help. With that, someone will try to help you.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, your question is hard to understand, too.

Comment: This question is no good: You should reed some books to inform yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to Form1's button click,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 from2 = new Form2();
    Control[] button = from2.Controls.Find("button1", true);
    button[0].Click += new EventHandler(ShowLabel);

    from2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Add this Form1 too (*Set the WORK label's visible property to false under properties*)

```
private void ShowLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Visible = true; //Setting WORK label's visible property to true
}
```